# How do I create new Vector4 objects when the values for instantiation are in strings?

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, text-parsing

I want to create a bunch of Vector4 objects and the values for instantiation are scraped from a config file which are stored in a List of strings.

The value of the strings are like "255, 0, 0 255" or "0, 0 255, 255" and etc.

Given I'm in a foreach loop and I'm about to create these Vector4 objects, how would I parse these strings such that I can extract out each individual integer and use it for instantiation, for example:

```
Vector4 v1 = new Vector4(255, 0, 0 255);
Vector4 v2 = new Vector4(0, 0, 255, 255);
```

Keep in mind, I want to make it an automatic process hence that's why I have a configuration file that includes all the Vector values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked the solution Grant Winney provided, but it would not handle all formatting requirements requested by Steven Chen. The delimiter has to be also space itself.

Also, I like these things to be wrapped up into an extension method :).
So here is slightly improved version with some tests for the wrong format causing exceptions.

```
public static class StringVector4Extensions
{
    public static Vector4 ToVector4(this string str, params string[] delimiters)
    {
        if (str == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("string is null");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) throw new FormatException("string is empty");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) throw new FormatException("string is just white space");

        if (delimiters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("delimiters are null");
        if (delimiters.Length <= 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("missing delimiters");

        var rslt = str
        .Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(float.Parse)
        .ToArray()
        ;

        if (rslt.Length != 4)
        throw new FormatException(  "The input string does not follow"     +
                                    "the required format for the string."  +
                                    "There has to be four floats inside"   +
                                    "the string delimited by one of the"   +
                                    "requested delimiters. input string: " +
                                    str                                   );
        return new Vector4(rslt[0], rslt[1], rslt[2], rslt[3]);
    }
}
```

Usage then is easy:

```
    var a =  "255, 0, 0 255".ToVector4(",", " ");
    var b =  "0, 0 255, 255".ToVector4(",", " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, parse the individual numbers, and pass them to the constructor.

```
string input = "255, 0, 0, 255";

var nums = input.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(float.Parse)
                .ToList();

Vector4 v1 = new Vector4(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3]);
```